# CSS span overflow auto or scroll not working with child element

Tags: html, css

I have the following setup:-

http://jsfiddle.net/YKXUb/1/

And the css is like this:-

```
.two { 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 border:1px solid green; 
 }

.hold 
{  
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 35%;
    border:1px solid green; 
}

.right {  height: 100%; border:1px solid green;}

.hold > img{width: 100%;height:100%;}

#one{ height: 300px; width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;}

.center{text-align:center;margin:0 auto;}
.rights{text-align:right;}

.main{width:100%;display:block;border:1px solid green;} 


.five{width:20%; border:1px solid green;float: left;}
.six{border:1px solid green;display:block;}
```

as you can see , the contents which exceeds the span width just keeps on going , I've tried with `overflow:scroll` and `overflow:auto` but nothing seems to work

Any help would be appreciated guys :)

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:auto` works for me

```
.six{border:1px solid green;display:block; overflow:auto}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YKXUb/4/)**

Comment: impossible , im using chrome and it dosent

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:auto` works but you need to add the height also:

`.six{
    border:1px solid green;
    display:block; 
    height:100px;
    overflow:auto
}`

> You need to Add height as per your requirement